# (AndroidStudio)Fix not Implemented exception when using Java and Kotlin in multi-module project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, multi-module, kotlin-java-interop

This is sample code for multi-module project of mine.

Module A

```java
// Test.java
package com.test

public interface Test {
  @NonNull
  String getTestName();
}
```

Module B

```kotlin
// Test.kt
package com.test

interface Test {
  val testName: String
}
```

```java
// ATest.java
package com.test.impl

public class ATest implements Test {
  @NonNull
  @Override
  public String getTestName() {
    return "It`s ATest";
  }
}
```

```kotlin
// BTest.kt
package com.test.impl

interface BTest : Test
```

```
// FinalTest.kt
package com.test.impl

class FinalTest : ATest(), BTest
```

For `FinalTest`, IDE warns that `Class 'FinalTest' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract val testName: String defined in com.test.impl.BTest`. But it works without compliation error. What should I do to remove that waring.

> I know a simple way is remove Test in Module A. But, assume there is some reason, so that we can't edit ATest or Test in Module A

I want use `FinalTest` without warning

Comment: In fact, I have some interface implements `LifecycleOwner` (simply call Foo). Few days ago, I converted `AFragment extends Fragment implements Foo` to kotlin code. And then `AFragment` warns like avobe. Since my project has dependencies for 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.5.0' and 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1' both.